# Callback in props of React component - correct way to fire

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a component which is like

```tsx
function Child(props: { onSelect: () => void }) {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        // want to fire onSelect here
    }, [...]);
    ...
}
```

Since props.onSelect might change every render (e.g. arrow function), I can't add it to the dependency list of useEffect and call it directly. I used a reducer instead:

```
const [, dispatch] = useReducer((state: undefined, action: T) => {
    props.onSelect(action);
    return undefined;
}, undefined);

useEffect(() => { 
    dispatch(...);
}, [...]);
```

But now I get the error "Warning: Cannot update a component (`Parent`) while rendering a different component (`Child`)."

What's the correct way to fire the parent's onSelect inside some useEffect?

Comment: Does your onSelect in parent re-render the child component?

Comment: Yes, it does some setState and passes it back to the child

Comment: What do you want to achieve? onSelect looks like a button click callback, why do you want to use it on useEffect?

Comment: My component has multiple elements that can be clicked, and the data from all of them is combined in a nontrivial computation via useMemo. I used useEffect to have the callback invoked only in one place instead of repeating it inside every onClick.

Comment: Why don't you pass ref to Child components to get that data on demand?

Comment: I made this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-jennings-b1061?file=/src/Parent.js

Comment: Hope you could make something like that.

Comment: I notice that ESLint is complaining on the deps list for useEffect. I want to avoid that and I don't think disabling the warning is the correct solution here either

Answer (score 1):

You mention

> Since `props.onSelect` might change every render (*e.g. arrow function*), I can't add it to the dependency list of `useEffect` and call it directly

You can, but you should make sure that it does not change if there is no reason.

You should use a useCallback for it on the parent component, so that it remains the same.

```
function Parent (){
...
   const onSelect = useCallback(() => {
     // set local state here
   }, []);
...

return ... <Child onSelect={onSelect} />
}
```

Comment: Why not use a normal function instead, like `function onSelect() {}` ?

Comment: Is this the only way? It seems untransparent to me to have a component that will cause an infinite loop if I don't specifically use useCallback, especially since I use arrow functions everywhere else. Seems like it can be a source of many bugs in the future if I forget that I have to use useCallback.

Comment: @SKK Is there a limitation to using arrow functions?

Comment: @NikhilPathania if the `onSelect` function is defined inside the `Parent` component it will be a new function on each re-render of the Parent. Which means that if used as a dependency on a `useEffect` in the child component, it will cause it to re-run on each re-render of the parent. That is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @SKK, it is not the component that is causing the infinite loop, but the props you provide it. You need to be very specific about when you want the `useEffect` to re-run and this is one of the things you need to take care when using hooks.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense to me. No other component requires wrapping the callback to prevent infinite rerenders. Just as you don't need useCallback for a button's onClick, I shouldn't need to use one here either...

Comment: @SKK you actually should use `useCallback` of button's `onClick` handlers to avoid attaching/detaching the handler in each re-render. The alternative is to not use it in a `useEffect` or not add it to the dependency list (*with all the problems this might naturally cause*).